# rotate text right side down using css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been constructing UI development for a year now and I want to explore new structures in regards to designing.

so I am styling my panel-heading that it would look something like this.

[image]

as of now I have only done the default style for `panel heading` via bootstrap css.

Comment: -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    writing-mode: lr-tb;

Comment: `transform: rotate(270deg)` - [CSS3 transform property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I just posted an example to how can make it with `position`. if you don't need then check 2nd snippet

```css
.main {
  position:relative;
}

.tilt {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:0px;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  color:#000;
  padding:0 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
}
.tilt p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="tilt">
<p>
HELLO
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
 .tilt {
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  color#000;
  padding:0 10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:22px;
}
.tilt p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tilt">
<p>
HELLO
</p>
</div>
```